# Replacing a specific string in java

Tags: java, string, replace

I am having problems with replacing a specific string in a user input string but is not generating the expected output.

```
String inputString="hellol lol";
String result = inputString.replaceAll("lol", "laugh out loud");
System.out.println("Normal Form:" + result);
```

*Input:* `hellol lol`

*Code output:* `hellaugh out loud laugh out loud`

*Expected output:* `hellol laugh out loud`

how do I fix this? thanks.

Comment: why don't you do `inputString.replace`?

Comment: It woks correct. You have to check your output. Result string is `hellaugh out loud laugh out loud`

Comment: there are two `lol`in your test string. Both get replaced. Its working as it should.

Comment: You’re ignoring the fact that lol must be preceded by white space to be considered a replace candidate

Comment: @CharlesShiller you will get the same output for that code.

Comment: True, but unless this is just an overly simplified example, why bring in regexp?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`replaceAll()` method takes regex to find the matches and replace them. The appropriate regular expression will do your job. Use `\\blol\\b` as regex.

```
inputString.replaceAll("\\blol\\b", "laugh out loud");
```

Here `\\b` is the word boundary that helps to identify the `lol` token